# Results are being sent back before search is done and result object is filled - mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I have a user object that has a property named categories, which should hold an array of objects that represent a category and its bookmarks. This array can have multiple instances of these objects. I have inside that object the properties "name" and "essays". "essays" is a reference to Essay model instances.

Here is part of how my model is set up. This is on the User schema:

```
categories: {type: Array,
            name: String,
            essays: {type: Array,
                        id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                            ref: 'Essay'}}
            }
,
```

I'm trying to do a search for User, then retrieve the categories property and get those ID's. After getting those ID's, I do a search in my Essay Schema for those ID's and retrieving all the data.

Here is the method I'm using:

```
controller.myCategories = function(req, res){
    var result = [];
    User.findOne({_id: req.headers.id}).then(function(user){
        user.categories.forEach(function(category, index, ins){

            var essayObj = {name: category.name};


            essayObj.essays = [];
            category.essays.forEach(function(essayId, index){
                var tempId = essayId;
                Essay.find({_id: tempId }).then(function(essay){
                    essayObj.bookmarks.push(essay)
                });
            });
            result.push(essayObj);
        })

    }).then(function(){
        res.status(200).send(result);   
        }); 
};
```

The issue I'm having is that the results are being sent before the the essays' data is filled in the object, and that object added to the results array. All I get is an empty essayObj with the name provided. What would be the best approach to have the code compiled in order?

Comment: Try reading the docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Hey gforce, was about to come back and 'answer my own question'. Thanks for the reply nonetheless! Yeah, I ended up redoing my schemas and added a categories model in which the essays were tied to. and categories were tied to user account. Did the populate request to gather the data and push it back into my angular app.